# Return Object in $rootScope Function (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am trying to return an object from a $rootScope function called retrieveUser() in AngularJS. The object is returned. I have run console.log() on the response of the function ran when $http is successful. Here is my $rootScope function:

```
    $rootScope.retrieveUser = function() {

        var apiUrl = "http://104.251.218.29:8080";

        if($cookies.get('tundraSessionString')) {

            var cookie = $cookies.get('tundraSessionString');

            $http({
                method: "POST",
                url: apiUrl + "/api/master/v1/auth/checkauth",
                data: "sessionString=" + cookie,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;',
                    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
                }
            }).then(function mySuccess(response) {

                if(response.data.event == "error") {

                    window.location = "/auth/logout";

                } else {

                    return response.data;

                }


            })

        } else {

            window.location = "/auth/login";

        }

    };
```

With this method, I access it in my controller such as this (and console.log() just to test my work):

```
vm.user = $rootScope.retrieveUser();
console.log($rootScope.retrieveUser());
```

But, I have yet to get this to work. I have tried specifying specific objects in an array in my $rootScope function. I know it runs, because I have the $rootScope consoling something when it is run, and it shows a console.log() of the response of the $http request. It looks like this:

```
Object {event: "success", table: Object}
event:"success"
table:Object
__proto__:Object
```

Yet, when I console.log() the vm.user with the function $rootScope.retrieveUser(), even though the function is supposed to be returning the object, I simply receive "undefined".

I have been banging my head on this for days, read some articles on functions/objects and I still cannot figure this out. We're two days in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
        if($cookies.get('tundraSessionString')) {

            var cookie = $cookies.get('tundraSessionString');

            //return a promise
            return $http({
                method: "POST",
                url: apiUrl + "/api/master/v1/auth/checkauth",
                data: "sessionString=" + cookie,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;',
                    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
                }
            }).then(function mySuccess(response) {

                if(response.data.event == "error") {

                    window.location = "/auth/logout";

                } 
                else {

                    return response.data;

                }


            })

        } 
        else {

            window.location = "/auth/login";

        }
```

and

```
$rootScope.retrieveUser().then(function(user){vm.user = user;})
```

Comment: This worked! I will remember to use the promise method from now on. I'm new to Angular. First app I've built. But I've gotten pretty far without a hiccup. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

What you are returning from retrieveUser when your cookie is set is what [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) returns, which is a [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q). Try this:

`$rootScope.retrieveUser().then(function(user){vm.user = user;})`

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined was in the Chrome console log.

Comment: The `retrieveUser` function should return a promise when using the .then approach. You can return the $http.get (which aso uses a promise)

Comment: yeah whoops I'm used to coffeescript, you also need to change it to `return $http({...`

Answer (score 0):

`retrieveUser` fn doesn't return your data :)
$http is asynchronous function and you should read about promises

```
function handleUser(user){
//do something
}

function retrieveUser(callback){
  $http({...}).then(function(response){
    callback(response.data.user);
  });
}
//how to use it:

retrieveUser(handleUser);
```

but first of all you may need a service for getting some data instead of using $rootScope

and secondly you can pass a user in your template in `script` tag
then you don't need another http request and user will be globaly available

`<script>var user=<?php echo json_encode($user);?></script>`